# Load a Blender Animation in Three.js using the Three.js (JSON) exporter

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender, exporter

I am making my first steps using JavaScript and playing with Three.js too.

I am learning how to export and load a Blender animation to Three.js and to make it I am using this example from the Three.js website: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse

I made a Blender animation (http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07429365581548704592) and when I export it an I load it to Three.js using the same code it doesn't run.

Do you know why I can't see the animation? I don't know if it is a limitation of the exporter or if it is a problem of my animation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Having spent many hours trying to get Blender animations working with the current release of three.js it is my conclusion that it is functionally if not completely impossible.

I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578758/exporting-blender-animations-cant-reproduce-three-js-example) here about this awhile back.  I ended up having to answer my own question.  I cover the convolutions you have to go through to get one of the examples (the simplest) working from the .blend file supplied with three.js itself.

The official examples and documentation recommend using ObjectLoader to load exports from Blender, but this doesn't work at all with the current three.js animation system.  The new animation stuff uses skinned meshes, and if you look at the ObjectLoader source (src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js) you'll see it doesn't have any logic which uses THREE.SkinnedMesh.  The new animation mixer, THREE.AnimationMixer, is not covered in the official three.js documentation.

Further, the Blender exporter is, depending on how you look at it, either very flaky or just plain broken.  I go into greater detail about this in the question I linked above, but for example the exporter changes the state of the model:  you have to go into pose mode, select all your bones, Alt-G and Alt-R to reset them to rest mode, then select the mesh and go into object mode before you do an export, and the export will transform all the bones back, so if you just export and then immediately export again, for example, you'll get inconsistent results.

From all of this I conclude that importing Blender animations into three.js is effectively if not completely broken, so if you're working on a project for immediate implementation you need to either change your pipeline to not use Blender or change the render end to not use three.js.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to say that you're right. The animation code is a bit out of control. By now I'm focusing on the new ColladaLoader so, even if it's not very efficient, at least we'll have a working workflow.

Comment: So practically it means that there is no way to load my animation with Three.js?